# Woocommerce Categories Showing 500

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

All of the categories on my Woocommerce store are showing as a 500 and the footer isn't loading.

See two examples here:

https://vaporizersdirect.com.au/category/vaporizers/
https://vaporizersdirect.com.au/category/grinders/

Does anyone have any clue what's going on? My homepage, blog and product pages seem to be fine.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried switching themes? Disabling plugins? Maybe something is wrong in the category template file.

Answer (score 0):

It was Advanced Custom Fields causing the problem.